# Form POST vs. AJAX POST

Tags: html, http

As far as I can see. The form post accepts a document while the ajax post accepts a xhr (I'm guessing this can be set)?

If that is the case, I can't use both in the same situation?

**Whare are the differences between these two methods of using POST**

Comment: @Amit "I can't use both in the same situation?"

Comment: One forces the browser to "hit" the page in its "action" attribute, the other one lets the JS perform the action of sending the data, where's the actual confusion and how could you use both in the same situation anyway? You can prevent the browser from doing its default action when submitting the form and transfer control to JS, where you would collect the data, send it somewhere and you wouldn't reload the page. I would bold it for you as well, but I don't think it would help. Essentially both do the same thing - send some data somewhere. They will produce the same http query too.

Comment: @Mjh That is a very appropriate answer right there!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use both and achieve the same result in terms of functionality, but I encourage you to rely on AJAX (jQuery) for providing a better overall user experience and lessen the load on the server (using php, you can only do what is needed, without the need to provide the full html output once more). Only update what actually changed.

When I was using jQuery and AJAX a few years back, I relied on AJAX to update parts of the UI without having the need to refresh the whole web page. Moreover, I used this to CRUD items in the management area and actually achieved a pretty nice user experience.

You can find more information about the jquery post method at [jQuery GET and POST details and usage examples](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)

Comment: Omg such a simple and understanding answer. So form post ***has*** to refresh the browser?

Comment: @KarlMorrison you can disable the default behaviour of the form to not change the current location

Comment: May I ***force*** the ajax post to redirect in the header? Or must I do it in a callback? (thinking of redirecting 302 server side for the post response header location)

Comment: I guess you can see the form like an ajax request with a default behaviour, the location change is done in a callback of the form

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while since I relied on this technologies. I will have some work to do with them in the near future, but for the moment I may be outdated :). I did not use ajax to force a redirect, but you should be able to redirect via the jquery.post callback and some javascript (jQuery). This shouldn't be a problem at all.

Answer (score 5):

It only makes sense to use one or the other in a context designed for that type of request. If the server would return a full, displayable resource (most commonly, a HTML document), use a form post so that the browser "redirects" to the result. If the server would return a result that only makes sense as part of an already visible resource, use xhr, parse the result and incorporate it into your page.